# Changing android password remotely

Tags: lock-screens, touchscreen, password, android-device-manager, remote-access

I have Nexus 4 with Android 5.1.1, lock with a PIN code.
Somehow the right 3 vertical dots don't response for touch, therefore I can't unlock my phone.

I want to cancel / change the password.

- I don't have root
- I don't remember if the Debug Mode is turn on or not, but my computer usually recognize the phone just after I unlock it - just connecting the USB do nothing.
- In addition, the command "adb devices" show nothing.
- Inserting 5 times the wrong password just locking me out, without giving me the "Forgot Password" option.
- Using the "Lock" option of the Android Device Manager put black shade on the screen with a chosen lock message, but I can't find the place to enter the new lock password I chose. I only see the 2 soft keys (circle and triangle) and when I touch them the screen move to the regular lock screen with the PIN code... [See Edit]

I'll appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
When I try to set new password through the Android Device Manager (ADM), after 2 seconds the website says: "Since Google has verified that a screen lock is already set, the password you entered won't be needed.", it's mean that my new password that I chose will not set, and that the reason I couldn't use it from the first place. Still looking for help!

Comment: Try clearing cache from your stock recovery. Report whether it works."Sometimes happens to me - Pattern to unlock does not show me as trying to unlock the device.
In order to put my pattern in to unlock the device I have to click on the Google Now short cut and I am then allowed to input my pattern to unlock the device. " some user posted this see if it works "https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42319"

Comment: Hi Daksh,
How do I clear the cache from outside?
The link you provided doesn't work.

Comment: My findings(Posted Above) says that swipe up from your navigation bar to invoke google now and after that close it and it will allow you to  enter Pattern. I didn't confirmed, This is what a user shared on google forums. Check and report if it works.Wish you Luck :)

Comment: i forgot to tell you how to clear cache.Press and hold the Volume Down button, then press and hold the Power button at the same time until the phone turns on. You'll see the word "Start" with an arrow around it. Press the Volume Down button twice to highlight "Recovery mode."Press the Power button to restart into Recovery mode.You'll see an image of an Android robot with a red exclamation mark and the words "No command."
While holding down the Power button, press and release the Volume Up button once. And then just clear cache and reboot your system.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description for cleaning the cache. Unfortunately it didn't help. If I understand you well, the second advice you mentioned is for case I don't see the PIN code dots. Sadly I see them all the time. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Then you need to do full wipe my friend. Wait for 1-2 days if someone comes-up with better method or a trick. Or if want to format system you can wipe the whole system with fastboot mode. Set up adb binaries with fastboot invoke the cmd if you use windows or terminal if you on linux and type "fastboot format userdata" and you'll get factory reseted device. and to go in fastboot use method above but select bootloader instead of recovery. Regards:Daksh :)

Answer (score 2):

It might be a bit late but I had a similar issue and found a genius idea that might help others.

If you have an OTG cable, you can plug in a mouse and use that to unlock the phone, then cancel / change it as you normally would.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

in your phone, go to recovery, wipe/ clear cache then reboot the phone. wait for 5 minutes, then through this link to lock the pin with new pin https://www.google.co.in/android/devicemanager

use the newly entered pin in the above link to unlock ur device

i forgot to tell you how to clear cache.Press and hold the Volume Down button, then press and hold the Power button at the same time until the phone turns on. You'll see the word "Start" with an arrow around it. Press the Volume Down button twice to highlight "Recovery mode."Press the Power button to restart into Recovery mode.You'll see an image of an Android robot with a red exclamation mark and the words "No command." While holding down the Power button, press and release the Volume Up button once. And then just clear cache and reboot your system

Answer (score 0):

just try to enter wrong pattern or pass code for 5 or 6 times,then one dialog will appear saying you have entered wrong code and bla bla. Hit the ok button. then at the right bottom corner you will find one option called "Forgot Password?". Tap on that, then it will going to tell you to enter the email and password. Enter your gmail id and password. It will unlock your phone.

Comment: Quoting from the question: *Inserting 5 times the wrong password just locking me out, without giving me the "Forgot Password" option.*

Comment: This thing has been rolled out from roms after update to *lollipop* version.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe logon to your Devicemanager and try to unlock it from there?

https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager
you should be able to unlock it there under "LOCK" ...
approaching from the "other" side to unlock your phone requires obviously Network Connection;).

After Login to Google ADM:
- Select your Device 
- Select LOCK
- Enter Temp Password (you don't have to enter the recovery msg)
- Hit LOCK again
- confirmation should now be on Screen
- now, you should be able to see a Password field
- enter your temp Password
- rest your lockscreen Settings!!!